# Set Ethernet Network as Metered Connection in Windows 8

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, lan, ethernet

Windows 8 introduced a new feature which allows users to set any Wi-Fi network as metered so that they can check their bandwidth usage:

[image]

[[img credit]](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-8-airplane-mode-metered-connections-in-network-settings/)

But, it doesn't allow users to set any Ethernet network as metered:

[image]

So, is there a trick/workaround to do it?

Comment: [Ethernet network connections can't be set to metered.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/metered-internet-connections-frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 2):

You can't set Ethernet as metered.

Source: [Metered Internet connections: Frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/metered-internet-connections-frequently-asked-questions) — What are the recommended settings?

---

Setting the connection to metered has the downside that your settings and files are not synced.

If your intention is to get network data usage statistics, you should use third-party tools instead.

Comment: There are options to turn on syncing for metered connections under Settings->Change PC settings->Sync your settings. It is at the bottom and there are separate roaming/non-roaming toggles.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting in the registry that will set the Ethernet connection as metered.

The setting is

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\
>
> Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost

Setting it to 2 will make the connection metered.

(taken from [tenforums.com](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/35656-ethernet-connection-set-metered-unmetered-windows-10-a.html))

Answer (score 1):

Physical Ethernet connections cannot be set as a metered connection without using any addons. The same applies to USB Tethered phones. You cannot set these as a metered connection. This feature was builtin with Wireless Hotspots in mind or Wireless Tethering from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know your data usage, you can use third party software.

And, as usual [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/) has a  [post](http://lifehacker.com/244649/download-of-the-day-freemeter-bandwidth-monitor--windows) about this very topic. It suggests using [FreeMeter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemeter/).

I don't think there are any tricks to mark LAN connections as metered as @KarthikT pointed out.

P.S. lifehacker *looks* down. Access [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vQnBbGqHY5YJ:lifehacker.com/244649/download-of-the-day-freemeter-bandwidth-monitor--windows+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk).

Comment: Blame sandy, they're part of gawker and most of their sites are apparently running off tumblr for the duration of the ... emergency going on.

Answer (score 0):

Natively, Windows 8 cannot set a physical connection as metered.
Still, there is software out there which can do that job pretty efficiently, and nicely easy as well.

My suggestion goes to [NetWorx](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43561/ask-how-to-geek-how-can-i-monitor-my-bandwidth-usage/)

Answer (score -1):

You can also try [bitmeter OS](http://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeteros).