# Windows 10 won't set USB tethering as Metered

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, windows-10-v1709

I'm using a laptop with USB tethering from my Android phone.

This option exists and can be turned on/off, but my option doesn't persist after exiting this screen and going back, so I guess the option isn't saved at all.

[image]

I tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1078336/688600) and set

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost\Ethernet
```

to `DWORD:2`, rebooted Windows and monitored for a few minutes with Task Manager, but nothing seemed to start behaving any differently.

The Android phone acts like a USB network adapter and I think it's irrelevant here (any USB adapter would behave the same). I'm using Windows 10 Fall Creator update (Updated November 2017), 64-bit Enterprise.